# conting of input names

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, count

I have a python homework which I need to take `n` from input to know how many names I have to take from input, save them to a dictionary then count how many each name was inputed, something like voting system.
so far I couldn't save my input into a dic.
Because I stored all inputs in a list after I assign my list with a dict, it turns to str.

for example:

```
how many vote u want to input : 4

take your votes:

jack

jasmin

jack 

sara
```

result:

```
jack 2

jasmin 1

sara 1
```

My code:

```
vorodi=[]
n=int(input())
counter={}
for i in range(0,n):
    vorodi.append(input())


for letter in vorodi:
    if letter not in counter:
        counter[letter]+=1
    else:
        counter[letter]=1

print(counter)
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here? there is no question. And your conditions are backwards. `if letter not in counter` it means this is the first so you want to do `counter[letter] = 1`, `else` it is already in the dict so you do `counter[letter] += 1`

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case where you will want to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). With `defaultdict` you specify the type of new keys and so if the key is not present it will be initialized to the default of the type specified. So you could do:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

n = int(input())
counter = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(n):
    counter[input()] += 1

print(counter.items())
```

---

**OR:**

with regular dict using the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method with the default argument:

```py
n = int(input())
counter = {}
for i in range(n):
    name = input()
    count = counter.get(name, 0)
    counter[name] = count + 1
```

---

**OR:**

with regular dict using the [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method with the default argument:

```py
n = int(input())
counter = {}
for i in range(n):
    name = input()
    counter.setdefault(name, 0)
    counter[name] += 1
```

---

To print it as you showed you can simply iterate the dict afterwards:

```py
for k,v in counter.items():
    print(k, v)
```